# How to adjust cli output into pretty columns

Tags: text-processing, command-line, columns

Let's say I have some CLI one-liner, which outputs some lines of text with space-separated parts. Those parts should logically be columns, but because of text width it doesn't look so.

How could I automatically format such output to make it pretty columns?

For example, I have output like

```
Alice param1 param2345 32768 50 16
Bob param2345 param1 512 10 1
_debug_user_ param0 param0 0 0 0
```

And I want to make it like

```
Alice        param1    param2345 32768 50 16
Bob          param2345 param1    512   10 1
_debug_user_ param0    param0    0     0  0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Linux `column(1)`:

```
column -t <file.txt
```

With BSD `rs(1)`:

```
rs 0 6 <file.txt
```

With `awk(1)`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { for(i=1; i<NF; i++) if(length($i)>w[i]) w[i]=length($i) }
     FNR!=NR { for(i=1; i<NF; i++) $i=sprintf("%-" (w[i]+1) "s", $i); print }' \
        file.txt file.txt
```

Comment: `column -t` is what I searched for, thank you!